# Disable future dates in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker, future, disable-link

Is it possible to disable future date from today?

Let say today is 23/10/2010, so 24/10/2010 onwards are disabled.

Sorry I am very new in jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes, indeed. The datepicker has the maxdate property that you can set when you initialize it.

Here's the codez

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date, minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12) });
```

Comment: Remember that when setting javascript's `Date` object use month-1. So, Jan is 0 and Dec is 11. This just slipped my mind for a few minutes.

Answer (score 38):

```
$(function() { $("#datepicker").datepicker({  maxDate: '0'}); });
```

Comment: We can use with out single quotes also for ex: `maxDate: 0`

Comment: nice.  I needed this for Date of Death.  End user kept predicting the death of people.

Answer (score 14):

Try This:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    endDate: new Date()
});
```

It will disable the future date.

Comment: endDate works,  maxDate doesn't work for me, thanks @pankaj

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following.

```
$("#selector").datepicker({
    maxDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Code for Future Date only with disable today's date.

```
 var d = new Date();
         $("#delivdate").datepicker({
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: base_url+"images/cal.png",
         minDate:new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)),
         buttonImageOnly: true
        });
         $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').attr('title','');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please avoid putting words in Caps and bold unless they are very important.

Answer (score 3):

Date for the future 1 year can be done by

```
$('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate:(0), maxDate:(365)});
```

you can change the date format too by the parameter `dateFormat`

Comment: [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars) can be visited for further **datepicker** parameters.

Answer (score 0):

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker

use zebra date pickers:

```
$('#select_month1').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: false,
  format: 'Y-m-d',
  pair: $('#select_month2')
});

$('#select_month2').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: 1, format: 'Y-m-d',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, datepicker supports max date property.

```
 $("#datepickeraddcustomer").datepicker({  
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",  
             maxDate: new Date()  
        });
```

Comment: How is your answer different than the currently accepted one?

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#thedate,#dateid').datepicker({
     changeMonth:true,
         changeYear:true,
         yearRange:"-100:+0",
         dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy" ,
         maxDate: '0',
     });
});
```