# jquery datepicker validation

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

How can I restrict the user from entering a future date?

This is the view:

```js
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ARRIVING_DT,new { @class="date"})

$(".date").datepicker({   
    changeMonth: true,   
     changeYear: true,   
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' ,
     selectOtherMonths: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showStatus: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../../Content/themes/base/images/i_cal.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Choose a Date'
          });
```

I am trying to write the valdation attribute for this as:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Date of Departure")]
    public object DEPARTURE_DT { get; set; }
```

What else need to be writen? The Range attribute is also not working. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: have you tried using minDate and/or maxDate? maxDate:0 may do the trick. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: [Check this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/jquery-ui-date-picker-future-date

Answer (score 1):

To disable future dates add:

```
maxDate: new Date,
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but still I am able to select a future date.

I tried:
maxDate: new Date
maxDate: '0'
maxDate: "+1D"

Is there any specific order of writing the options or some other necessary options which must be written before maxDate?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#<%= txtDate.ClientID  %>').datepicker({
                 maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
             });
This will disable the future dates from getting entered. another best way for the question.
```