# Disabling future date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have code in j query for date-picker. but now i want to disable the future date in j query calender. the date picker is working fine but my problem is to disable the future date from the current date. i.e the cannot select the date in future..

```
$(function(){
$("#datepicker1").datepicker();
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");

$("#datepicker2").datepicker();
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable future dates in jQuery UI Datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting [Max-Date](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) will solve your problem:

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date() );
```

> Set a maximum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +1w'), or null for no limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    maxDate: 0d
});
```

lots of options like `minDate`, `beforeload` and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed. The datepicker has the maxdate property that you can set when you initialize it. you can see here http://blogvani.com frontpage where date is  set the maxdate to the current date.

```
  ("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date, minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#DeathDate").datepicker({ maxDate: '0' });
```