# Disable future dates after today in Jquery Ui Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to disable all the future dates after today in Jquery Ui Datepicker

**Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/541/) :**

**Code :**

```
$( "#start_date" ).datepicker(

        { 
            maxDate: '0', 
            beforeShow : function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).datepicker('option','maxDate', jQuery('#end_date').val() );
            },
            altFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

        }

);

$( "#end_date" ).datepicker( 

        {
            maxDate: '0', 
            beforeShow : function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).datepicker('option','minDate', jQuery('#start_date').val() );
            } , 
            altFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

        }

);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable future dates in jQuery UI Datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });
 });
```

Or you can achieve this using as below:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: 0 });
});
```

[**Reference**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL2Bc/145/)

[UPDATED ANSWER](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/544/)

Comment: @Amit: Thanks for the answer, it is working as a charm.

Comment: Somehow this `$('#birth_date').datetimepicker({
                timepicker:false,
        format:'d/m/Y',
        maxDate : '0',
                maxDateTime:new Date()
            });
` doesn't work.

Comment: $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });
 }); is working for me

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me `endDate: "today"`

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "top",
        endDate: "today"

  });
```

[SOURCE](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: This `endDate: "today"` helped me

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I have given this attribute to the input tag

`data-date-start-date="0d"
 data-date-end-date="0d"`

Comment: This should be preferred if you have a generic JS code for all datepickers and out of those you need to restrict date in one or two fields.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: new Date });
  });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL2Bc/144/)

FYI: while checking the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate), found that it also accepts numeric values too.

> **Number**: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days
>   from today and -1 represents yesterday.

so `0` represents today.  Therefore you can do this too

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: 0 });
```

Comment: Please modify my fiddle

Comment: @CodeHunter may I know for which one `start_date` or `end_date`?

Comment: For start date its obvious

Answer (score 3):

Change maxDate to current date

```
maxDate: new Date()
```

It will set current date as maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are appending Dtpicker,use the following code

```
$('#enddate').appendDtpicker({
    "dateOnly": true,
    "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "closeOnSelected": true,
    maxDate: new Date()         
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Datepicker does not have a `maxDate` as an option. I used this endDate option. It worked well.

```
$('.demo-calendar-default').datepicker({
  autoHide: true,
  zIndex: 2048,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  endDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

//Disable future dates after current date

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());
```

//Disable past dates after current date

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());
```

Comment: your code to disable past dates doesnt look right.. shouldn't it be start date?

Answer (score -4):

```
maxDate: new Date()
```

its working fine for me disable with current date in date range picker

Comment: I don't think this adds anything to the existing answers.