# JQuery Datepicker find next disabled date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

When a user selects a date by clicking on the calendar, is it possible to find the next/closest disabled future date.

From what I've seen disabled dates do not output a date in the markup, they only output the day (I need the year,month,day), so looking for the next 'ui-state-disabled' element wont work.

Comment: surely it must only be disabled barbecue you disabled it? in which case you already know

Comment: yes that's true I did disable it, but it bears no relation to the selected date the user clicks. when the user selects a date I need to look ahead on the calendar & find the next disabled date –  kb

Comment: I do not understand the point. You probably use an array to store disabled dates and your `beforeShowDay` function looks uses `$.inArray`, so why not loop over the same array?

Comment: Try to approach the problem from the other side. Don't analyze the DOM elements of datepicker - but work with data. Is that your function defined the disabled dates? If so (I hope it is) - use the same logic/data to find the next disabled date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK, there is **no [official resource](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** for finding out the disabled dates in jQuery Datepicker.

However *jQuery UI Datepicker is a library upon Javascript, there is always a workaround.*  Below is a workaround I have tried.

### Step #1:

Below is a way to disable a list of dates in jQuery Datepicker.

```
var array = ["2014-03-14", "2014-03-18", "2014-03-16", "2014-04-01"]

$('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    },
    onSelect: function (date) {
            console.log(findNextDisabledDateWithinMonth(date));
    }
});
```

Now here my approach to get the next disabled date within the month.

### Step #2:

```
function findNextDisabledDateWithinMonth(date) {
    var currentDate = Number(date.split('-')[2]);
    var month = $('.ui-datepicker-title>.ui-datepicker-month').text(); //Number(date.split('-')[1])
    var year = $('.ui-datepicker-title>.ui-datepicker-year').text();  //Number(date.split('-')[0])
    var nextConsectiveDates = [];
    $.each($('.ui-state-disabled').find('.ui-state-default'), function (i, value) {
        var numericDate = +$(value).text();
        if (currentDate < numericDate) {
            nextConsectiveDates.push(numericDate);
        }
    });
    var nextDisabledDate = nextConsectiveDates[0] + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    return nextDisabledDate;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/CxNNh/673/)

**NOTE:** *This is work only for the selected date's month*

---

### Approach #2

As @ Salman A mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596099/jquery-datepicker-find-next-disabled-date#comment34732345_22596099), I feel the best way is to go with it.  Since my approach will is constrained within month.

Here is an elegant approach to solve your problem.

```
var array = ["2014-05-01", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-16"];
// Convert all those string dates into Date array
var arrayAsDateObjects = convertStringToDateObject(array);

$('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    },
    onSelect: function (date) {
        alert(findNextDisabledDateWithinMonth(date).toDateString());
    }
});

//To find the next exact disabled date based on the selected date
function findNextDisabledDateWithinMonth(date) {
    var splitDate = date.split("-");
    var selectedDate = new Date(splitDate[0], Number(splitDate[1]) - 1, splitDate[2]);
    var nextDisabledDate = null;
    $.each(arrayAsDateObjects, function (i, ele) {
        if (selectedDate < ele) {
            nextDisabledDate = ele;
            return false;
        } else {
            nextDisabledDate = "No Disabled dates available";
        }
    });
    return nextDisabledDate;
}

//convert all the string dates to Date object
function convertStringToDateObject(array) {
    var ls = [];
    $.each(array, function (i, ele) {
        var splitDate = ele.split("-");
        var date = new Date(splitDate[0], Number(splitDate[1]) - 1, splitDate[2]);
        ls.push(date);
    });
    // Sort the dates in ascending order(https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/1671639)
    ls.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    return ls;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/CxNNh/676/)

for sorting dates, I took reference from [@Phrogz 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/1671639)

Answer (score 0):

I hoped that the datepicker would have had a function built in for this, but looks like it doesn't. So I had to just look through my list of disabled dates & determine the answer from the list, which is what I was trying to avoid, as the list is huge.

Comment: We can set minDate & maxDate parameters in Datepicker.Chek out this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006328/disable-future-dates-after-today-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: What it represents your list? Is this 1-dimensional array of values ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a day from the date picker on my website.

```
<td class=" " 
  onclick="DP_jQuery_139.datepicker._selectDay('#Dob',2,2014, this);return false;">
     <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a>
</td>
```

Could you parse the on click for the parent td? Or does disabling a date also remove the parent on click event? Anyway here something that might point you in the right direction. Untested, you can fiddle with it. It's late and I need to get some rest.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-default').click(function() {
   var clickhandler = $(this).closest('td').next('td:has(a.ui-state-disabled)').attr('onclick');
   var monthYear = clickhandler.replace(/^.*,?/,'').replace(/, this.*/,'').split(',');
   // do something with your monthYear array here
});
```