# Restrict selection of disabled dates in DateRange input bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Is there is a way to restrict a selection in Bootstrap DateRange when a user select a **disabled day** or **disabled date**

I have setup an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/x6ncnhLv/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
  datesDisabled: ['01/06/2016', '01/21/2016']
});
```

For example if a user select Friday to Monday the selection should not get applied because Sat and Sun are disabled days.

The same applies to dates as well.

Comment: It seems that there is no solution for the above. What i mange to do for those interested is to create a new php file where i pass the dates from the datepicker and verify their correctness. I load the content of this file via Ajax so you can see visually and live the output. With this way a user can check if the date range that he selected are within the rules.

Comment: Check the answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738226/how-to-prevent-selecting-date-range-in-which-there-is-a-disabled-date-in-between