# Validate date of birth greater than today?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to validate html `<input type='date'/>` is greater than today?

The following is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2" for='id_dateOfBirth'>Birth Date </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class='form-control' name="dateOfBirth" id='id_dateOfBirth' type='date'>
</div>
```

I want to check whether date is greater than today using JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried by yourself? What is not working? Please show us your code.

Comment: Why would you want DOB to be greater than today?

Comment: okay i want a javascript which validate date of birth is greater than today?

Comment: i want to check that entered dob is greater than today or not .

Comment: Do you know how to write JavaScript? Have you done any research on how to validate input? And what do you mean by "greater than today"?

Comment: OP may be wanting to restrict the date input value be not a future date

Comment: yes i have try lot of javascripts none of it works perfect

Comment: @OP: use a date picker library that allows to disable future dates.

Comment: @OP: here is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/22006447/767881

Comment: @RavinderReddy using a library for such small things does not make any sense to me. May be you need to do something else.

Comment: _**@NiteshGoyal**_: read the solution given at referred SO link. simple solution. no explicit disabling is required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I understand from your question is - "Before posting the form, you'd like to check if the DOB field has a date that must not be greater than today's date.". If this is correct, then try this, Hope this help -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDOB() {
        var dateString = document.getElementById('id_dateOfBirth').value;
        var myDate = new Date(dateString);
        var today = new Date();
        if ( myDate > today ) { 
            $('#id_dateOfBirth').after('<p>You cannot enter a date in the future!.</p>');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If someone is not agreed with the answer, then please let us know the reason before giving a negative vote. Thanks!

Comment: thx it works very fine for met

Comment: @stone If you are happy with the answer then you can upvote the answer for me :-)

Comment: how to use checkDOB()  it should rasie error in input box not an popup

Comment: Replace the alert statement in the checkDOB method with the code - $('#id_dateOfBirthr').after('<p>You cannot enter a date in the future!.</p>');

Answer (score 1):

If you can use php do:
`<input type="date" name="date1" max=<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); >`

if only js:

```
document.getElementById("id_dateOfBirth").setAttribute("max", today);
```

where today is eg 2017-03-10 
to get this date use eg :

```
      new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0]
```

Comment: You'll block put higher date than today in this case