# how to limit JQuery datepicker without disabling manual input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using a simple datepicker that limits input to be past only:

```
$( ".datepicker.past" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "0d"
});
```

I **do not** want to disable manual entries, but I do need the manual entry to conform to the datepicker limits. What's the easiest / best way to achieve this?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: The datepicker widget only controls what happens when you use it, it doesn't override manual entries. So either disable manual entries, or use your own Javascript validation to check it.

Comment: @Thangaraja How does that help, the answers there show exactly what he's doing?