# How can Disable back date in a Calender

Tags: jquery

I want to disable the dates after the current date in my program. I have a date picker written in JavaScript.

sorry for my any mistake ..actually here is I am new

Here is  my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script src=" jquery.js"></script>
    <script src=" jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="datetime">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
        step: 1
    });
    $("#datetime").datepicker({minDate: new Date()});
</script>
</html>
```

I am trying so many datepicker query  but all are not working ...backdates are not disable ...so can you help me

Comment: that's depending on the lib you're using

Comment: how can know this  lib it working for disable back date?

Comment: There should be a URL at the top of the JS file which links to the project website which has the documentation you can follow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable future dates in jQuery UI Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datepicker is implemented to use

```
$( "#datetime" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

If your jQuery plugin minDate functionality is same, you will disable past dates.
[Read more here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: @Abhichauhan Nice to know. Would you like to accept the answer with a right tick.

Answer (score -1):

First your opening body tag is not complete and the other answer to your question is add **disabled** to your input field

Comment: The question is asking how to disable selection of past dates, not how to disable the control completely.